# Rails 5 test database out of sync with development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am encountering an issue with `Rails 5.1.2` running `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053)` where every time I run a migration it puts the test DB into a state running tests is impossible, and to get both the test database and development database into a state where they are both working, the following migration commands must be run in this order:

```
rails db:drop
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused because I had a migration creating a table, and trying to create and index on a column I had renamed, so an index on [null] was appearing in the schema, which apparently the development db can deal with, but the test db can't without some shenanigans involved in how the db is migrated

In order to get both the dev and test DB working to the point where I could run tests. Eventually I tracked down the index on a null column in an existing table in `db/schema.rb` it was a fairly simple matter to find the index command in the table creation migration and wipe it out. After that the DB can be brought back into form with just

```
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```